# How to use equals in a FilterExpression for DyanmoDb API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a lot of trouble scanning and then using FilterExpression to filter based on a single value. I have looked at the api documentation and other stack overflow questions, but am still having trouble figuring the proper syntax for this. Since I am also using react and javascript for the first time, this may be a problem with my understanding of those.

Below is what I am trying to use as a filter expression. uploadId is the field name in the Dynamo database table and event.pathParameters.id is the variable that should resolve to the value that the scan results are filtered on.

```
FilterExpression: "uploadId = :event.pathParameters.id"
```

Below is the code in within context:

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
    import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context, callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName: "uploads",
    FilterExpression: "uploadId = :event.pathParameters.id"
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
    if (result.Item) {
      // Return the retrieved item
      callback(null, success(result.Item));
    } else {
      callback(null, failure({ status: false, error: "Item not found." }));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use Expression with `ExpressionAttributeValues`. `params` should look like this.

```
const params = {
    TableName: "uploads",
    FilterExpression: "uploadId = :uid",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":uid" : {S: event.pathParameters.id} //DynamoDB Attribute Value structure. S refer to String, N refer to Number, etc..
    } 
};
```